# Keyboard shortcut to switch to Russian language mode in Windows

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

If you have multiple input languages installed in Windows (under the Region and Language control panel item → Keyboards and Languages), is there a quick way to switch between languages (e.g. switch between English and Russian keyboards)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default shortcut to rotate languages is <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

If you have more than two languages, I suggest you to set separate shortcuts for the different languages in **Language preferences → Advanced settings → Change language bar hot keys**

For example, I have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> set to Russian and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> set to Japanese IME, as I have 8 more layouts installed and it would take way too long to rotate through them all.

**Update Aug 17:** As of Windows 10, there is also the new <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut available.

Comment: 10 layouts? I have six and I thought that I'm crazy. But ten! :)

Comment: Official documentation: http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/Keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

The default shortcut key to switch between input languages is <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> in Windows (tested on Windows 7).

Comment: It is actually just Alt + Shift, i.e. the right ones work as well.

Comment: I didn't realize that (it shows Left Alt in the Windows dialog). Thanks!